# Java String Comparison is failing, using equals method

Tags: java, string, comparison

```
do
{
    System.out.println("Type another number to continue or type 'End' to end");
    end = scan.next();

    if("end".equals(end)==false||"End".equals(end)==false)
    {
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(end);   


        int j = 0;          
        while (j < num2)
        {
            System.out.println(name);
            j++;
        }

        if(j == 0)
        {
            num2 = 0;   
        }
    }   
} while("end".equals(end)==false||"End".equals(end)==false);
```

The String comparison keeps failing.  When you type 'End' or 'end' it tries to parse it into an integer and returns an error.  Idk why this is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure if the if is necessary, I put that in because I thought it was trying to parse into an Int before it ended the loop and that was causing the error.  However, I still get the error with the conditional.

Comment: Maybe cause you are actually parsing it ? `num2 = Integer.parseInt(end);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if("end".equals(end)==false||"End".equals(end)==false)
```

Think about it: that would always be true. If the user typed `end`, then the first case would be `true` and the second `false`.

You could fix it by using `&&` instead, but a better method would be:

```
if(!("end".equalsIgnoreCase(end)))
```

Also, so you don't have to check the condition twice, you could just use

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type another number to continue or type 'End' to end");
    end = scan.next();
    if ("end".equalsIgnoreCase(end)) break;
    // now do your stuff
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(end);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Man, the problem is always so obvious once you see it.  Thanks errybody.

Comment: @ChristianBaker You're welcome! If this answer solved the problem, please click on the green check to the left so that the question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

This line will always be `true`:

```
if("end".equals(end)==false||"End".equals(end)==false)
```

because at least one of them will always be true.  You want it not to equal `"end"` *and* not to equal `"End"`.  Replace `||` with `&&`:

```
if("end".equals(end)==false && "End".equals(end)==false)
```

There's no need to compare the value with `false`; just use the `!` negation operator:

```
if(!("end".equals(end)) && !("End".equals(end)))
```

You will need to make a similar change to the condition at the end of your do-while loop.

Comment: I think a cleaner way for that line might be `if (!("end".equals(end) || "End".equals(end)))`, but personally I like passing the string to check into the method: `if (!(end.equals("end") || end.equals("End")))`. It's all preference really.

Comment: @Rogue They are logically equivalent: `not (condA || condB)` and `not condA && not condB`.  Also, most prefer using `"literal".equals(variable)"` to avoid a possible `NullPointerException` if `variable` is `null`.

Comment: Hm, I can see that perspective. Could potentially be easier since you wouldn't necessarily need to null check.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing `end` to int `num2` by the statement `num2 = Integer.parseInt(end);`.
That will you `NumberFormatException`